# An illegal reflective access operation has occurred: Problem trying to merge changefile with .pbf data

Tags: openstreetmap, java, osmosis

After downloading a changefile (525.osc.gz) and a planet file (planet-latest.osm.pbf) I am trying to merge the changes with the following command:

`osmosis --read-xml-change file="525.osc.gz" --read-pbf file="planet-latest.osm.pbf" --apply-change --write-pbf file="updated.osm.pbf"`

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil 
(file:/home/jovyan/osmosis/lib/default/protobuf-java-3.6.1.jar) to 
fieldjava.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of 
com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further 
illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future 
release
Aug 12, 2019 9:04:08 PM 
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.ActiveTaskManager 
waitForCompletion
SEVERE: Thread for task 1-read-xml-change failed
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Pipeline 
entities are not sorted or contain multiple versions of a single 
entity, previous entity type=Node, id=386274, version=15 current 
entity type=Node, id=386274, version=16.
```

Which goes on and on.

How do I debug this?

Comment: See also https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/3781

Comment: I'm just going to use [osmconvert](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert), it's easier, i can just do `osmconvert planet_old.osm changefile.osc -o=planet_new.osm`